# Seperate mounted dist still on base-disk

Tags: 20.04, mount, hard-drive

To start off - I am not used to Ubuntu etc. but I got to work on it and did what I thought would solve my problem.

I have 2 disks mounted, one is about 1 TB in size, the other 41 TB.

```
lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 1000G  0 disk
└─sda1   8:1    0 1000G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   0 48.8T  0 disk
└─sdb1   8:17   0 40.9T  0 part /home/eouser/pgdata
```

I thought that the data stored in the pgdata-directory will only be stored there, but apparently as it is a "child of a child"  (dont know the right terms, sorry) and the data is present on both disks.

I confirmed this with:

```
sudo du -h /home/eouser/pgdata/
sudo du -h /
```

which shows the directory for both.

Obviously I don't want it this way as the data on pgdata is getting big and the disk space on the other drive is full.
Is it possible to solve this?

I am using a Virtual machine with Ubuntu 20.04 with only command-line available.

EDIT 1:

df -h returns:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             63G     0   63G   0% /dev
tmpfs            13G  1.4G   12G  11% /run
/dev/sda1       939G  939G     0 100% /
tmpfs            63G     0   63G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            63G     0   63G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
s3fs             16E     0   16E   0% /codede
tmpfs            13G     0   13G   0% /run/user/1001
/dev/sdb1        41T  636G   39T   2% /mnt/pgdata
tmpfs            13G     0   13G   0% /run/user/1000
```

Comment: I'm not quite following the "the data is present on both disks". The `pgdata` location is mounted to a directory inside your `/home` directory. Linux-based systems display file and disk usage a little differently than Windows. You can use `df -h` to confirm how much data is being used on which storage device, which should confirm that you do not have duplicate data (unless you specifically copied the data to a second location) 

Comment: As I am looking on the results of df -h i guess the mount-point was not where I thought it was. Seems that the 2nd hard drive is mounted on /mnt/pgdata. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: @matigo any idea why I have different mountpoints shown in df -h and lsblk?

Comment: I dont really understand why my 1TB disk is "full" as the data should only be stored on the other one. But if I use "du -h /home" it shows the "/home/eouser/pgdata"-directory with ~650GB in the list. This should be the mount-point for my second drive? Is there a way to check what is actually stored on the /-mounted drive?

Comment: You're right. I missed that. You'll want to use `du -h | sort -h` to list directories, then begin narrowing down which directories specifically are taking up that much space. As the `/` is full, you may get a bunch of warnings while doing this, though. One place to check first would be `/var/log` to see if there are any log files that are ridiculously large. If there are, then your system is screaming about a problem ...

Comment: Ok so I will go through the different directories and see if something is unexpectedly large besides the pgdata-directory as this would be expected to be big and shoudl be stored on the other drive?

Comment: Yep. Be sure to check your logs and PostgreSQL data directory just to make sure things are not misconfigured 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because how Linux file systems work. Linux has a single file structure. Any file you can access, independent on what drive it resides, can be found under that single file system.

Files on drives can only be accessed if the file system of that drive is mounted in that single file structure.

Your partition `sda1` that exists on drive `sda` is mounted at the top of the file structure: `/`. It contains the system files.

You have a second drive, `sdb`, that contains a partition `sdb1`. That partition is mounted on a directory `pgdata` in the directory `eouser` that in turn exists in the directory `home` that can be found in the root directory `/`, hence the path `/home/eouser/pgdata`.

The `df` command will traverse your entire file structure to count the size of the files. So if you start at the top (`/`) also `/home/eouser/pgdata` is included. If you start in the latter, you only count size in the latter.

Comment: As I said in the comments below the question: I have no idea what is causing my "base-disk" (mounted on /) to get full then. There shouldnt be any data written to it so I have to find out what happened.

Comment: Your `/` partition sda1 actually is extremely (too) small, and full. That is a big problem that will cause your system to malfunction. But it is a different problem than the one you asked.

Comment: Yeah the idea was that the / partition is only used for small amounts of data like setup data etc. and the big chunk of data is stored on the big partition. This big partition is used as a volume for my docker-container containing all the postgis-data.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I got my question answered even though my problem still stands but seems to be coming from somewhere else